# CompletableFuture: Why we need stages at all?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, future, completable-future

i did research but didn't find a adequate answer for this question.

Why we need more stages than on stage.

**One Thread -> One Big Task(A,B,C,D)
VS
CompletableFuture with the stages A, B, C, D**

So my answer would be the following:

- If I have more stages, i can split the task over different methods and classes
- If I have more stages, it's more fair executing the whole task related to other whole tasks. What I mean with that? Let's say we have in our system only one Thread. If I execute it that way -> One Big Task(A,B,C,D), then my next big Task (W,X,Y,Z) get the chance to be executed, after the first big task is ready. With CompletionStages, there it is more fair: because A,W,B,C,X,Y,Z,D could be the execution order

Are there for my last point any metrics/rules, how small I should split the big task into sub-tasks?

- Is my last point a point for the stages in CompletableFutures?
- Is my first point a
  point for the stages in CompletableFutures?
- Are there other points for using the stages of CompletableFutures?

Comment: Imagine you have tasks A, B and C where A is followed by B or C depending on a variable x. Now imagine x is not set before A is worked on. There, you need stages if you wanna do things asynchronously here.

Comment: but if i use only one completableFuture pipeline, then x is calculated before B and C are executed, the same if i use this "stages" in one thread. Im not thinking about secenarious CompletalbeStages.allOf()/anyOf() is involved, to mix different pipelines; i mean the normal thenApplyAsync-methods in one pipeline

Comment: What I mean is, you can calculate x and work on A asynchronously in the meantime. Then, depending on your result for x, you chain B or C to A.

Comment: yeah i understand, what you mean, t think that we can add this to my bullet-points,.... but maybe there are some more reasons for staging and for the direct-staging so cf.thenApplyAsync()..thenApplayAsync()..thenApplyAsync()
in your case this chain would be broken, and a conditional statement would be at some point inbetween there; that - what i said agreeing to you - is a good reason using CFs^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have the choice, like with

```java
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> method1())
    .thenApply(o1 -> method2(o1))
    .thenApply(o2 -> method3(o2))
    .thenAccept(o3 -> method4(o3));
```

and

```java
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    var o1 = method1();
    var o2 = method2(o1);
    var o3 = method3(o2);
    method4(o3);
});
```

or

```java
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> method4(method3(method2(method1()))));
```

there is no advantage in using multiple stages. In fact, the first variant is much harder to debug than the alternatives.

Things are different when the chaining does not happen at the same place. Think of a library having a future returning method, encapsulating something like `supplyAsync(() -> method1())`, another library calling that method, chaining another operation and returning the composition to the application which will chain yet another application.

Expressing the same in a single stage would only be possible when the methods invoked in the functions are still provided by each library’s API and have a sequential nature, i.e. we’re not talking about `thenCompose(…)` kind of stages.

But such chains are still hard to debug and project *Loom* is trying to solve this. Then, you’d express the operation as a call sequence, exactly like in the second or third variant even when the methods are potentially blocking, but run it in a virtual thread which will release the underlying native thread each time it would block.

Then, we have even less use for a linear chain of stages.

---

A remaining use case for creating a linear chain of dependent stages is to have *different executors*. For example

```java
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> fetchFromDb(), MY_BACKGROUND_EXECUTOR)
    .thenAcceptAsync(data -> updateSwingModel(data), EventQueue::invokeLater)
    .whenCompleteAsync((x, thrown) ->
         updateStatusBar(jobID, thrown), EventQueue::invokeLater);
```

here, writing the operation as a single block is not an option…

Comment: yeah the point with different executors, if forgot^^, you are right here.. Yeah Loom can be an game changer, if i know it right, Java 18 will introduce Loom in an experiment mode, i guess?
To the point: "there is no advantage in using multiple stages", isnt my fairness point a point  for that? If i split it down to more stages, the executor can do the job for more big-tasks, and if the executor is full, it don't have to finish first the big-tasks 1,2,3, and after then it can start with the big tasks 4,5,6 (Executor with 3 threads)

Comment: There is no guaranty that the executor will pick up tasks from another dependency chain in such a scenario. In fact, with the default executor, a Fork/Join thread pool, it is rather unlikely, as it prefers locally enqueued tasks (i.e. from its currently executed dependency chain). If you want interleaved execution, you are better off ensuring that the pool has enough threads and let the preemptive multitasking do its job.

Comment: ah i see, thats a good point, but if i have only cpu-intensive tasks, so i should take a pool which size is nearly the same as the cpu-core-size; if i take more, then i get worser performance, because of the preemptive multitasking; Exists there any other solution having only cpu-core much threads and a fair-policy?

Comment: Fairness and maximum throughput are at different ends. If fairness really is a concern, don’t hesitate to create more threads than cores. Yes, switching reduces the maximum throughput, but don’t overestimate the impact. Other attempts of adding fairness will likely cost more while achieving less.